# Redirecting conditionally without using component Angular

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have a lazy module having two component, first and second. The module is loaded for a route `lazy/:id`. Depending on the type of `id` (an API call will return the type of `id`), we have to load the first or second component. To achieve this, currently a third component named resolver is added to the `lazyModule`, which loads for the `path:''` route in lazyModule and makes the API call for `id`. The response is appended to the url and `this.router.navigate` is used to navigate to the `first` or `second` component.

The issue is that this functionality is being used in multiple places in the application and I would like to use a common code at a single place. Using a component with empty template doesn't appears to be a good idea. Is there any other way to achieve it maybe by using `guard/service/resolver` or any other feature.

I've made a minimal reproduction for this on stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8ylxq8?

Answer (score 0):

Service will work - because service will be a injector and if you just inject your service in root `module` you can make use of it in any module

Like this

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class HeroService {

  constructor() { }

}
```

You don't need to add the service in any of the `module` `provider` array - `provideIn` will take care of injecting in your root module

Finally - you are thinking of using it in many places that too while routing so you can call this service when routing happens and `navigate` to the specific `components` - to access some service before routing you can use `route resolver`

```
@Injectable()
class TeamResolver implements Resolve<Team> {
  constructor(private backend: Backend) {}

  resolve(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<any>|Promise<any>|any {
    return this.backend.fetchTeam(route.params.id);
  }
}
```

Insted of `this.backend.fetchTem()` method you can call your service - so you can remove your component and just mapp your `resolver` service

```
{
    path: 'team/:id',
    component: TeamCmp,
    resolve: {
      team: TeamResolver
    }
  }
```

Way to access your `resolver` in your routing !! since resolver is also a service you can use it in any of your routes

Hope this helps - happy coding !!

Comment: Already thought about this. The issue is that I am loading the `ResolverComponent` everytime without any use. Even with your suggestion, I would be loading TeamCmp.

Comment: Make your resolver component as service - you cannot load component everytime so try with service - Thanks

Comment: And how to use that service when I hit the default route `path:''`

Comment: Yeah just add a property as `resolve` in your route and map a resolver service - in that service you just call your service and try to navigate, the resolver will run first before routing